# Cookie unset() not properly

Tags: php, cookies

My problem cookie is not unset() properly.

Here is my code

```
$expire=time()+(60*60*24*7);
setcookie('ppt-superadmin',$user['login_id'],$expire,"/",$baseurl)
```

here `$baseurl="http://localhost/demo/`

This is working fine. And here is my logout.php code

```
session_start();
$expire=time()-(60*60*24*7);
unset($_SESSION['ppt-superadmin-login']);
setcookie('ppt_superadmin',"",$expire,"/",$baseurl);
unset($_COOKIE['ppt-superadmin']);
session_destroy();
```

I have tried both unset and setcookie() to a past time. BUt not working. I have echo its value, its showing value set at the time of login.
What is the problem here??

Comment: Do you have `display_errors` turned on?  Always when developing code `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` -- header errors are extremely common with cookie problems. Also, where did you check the unset cookie's value? Was it in the same script? You will not see it unset until a subsequent HTTP request. Best to inspect the cookie with your browser's developer tools rather than look at its value in PHP.

Comment: Ah, `$baseurl` should be a domain `localhost`, not a URL `http://localhost/...`

Comment: To unset a cookie, you just set the cookie again with an expiry timestamp in the past, like `time()-1` But why use a cookie, if you have a session?

Comment: Used cookie for remember me function

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes its turned on. Not showing any error.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thankyou.. Actually the issue with domain and the path. The issue is solved now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a a typo,

```
setcookie('ppt_superadmin',"",$expire,"/",$baseurl);
              ^
```

Make sure it's underscore or dash because at time of setting you have name with dash while at time of un-setting it, you used underscore.

Comment: Sorry.. Thats my spelling mistake. But its not solved the issue.

Comment: @Girish: If this was an actual mistake in your code, you should clear your cookies before testing again, if you don't you can't really be sure that this didn't fix the issue